# Is it possible to set a frame (or time) with Three.js AnimationMixer?

Tags: animation, three.js

In other words: how to get the values of a specific frame in a geometry animation?

I have tried using `AnimationMixer` as following:

- advance animation in 1 second: `mixer.update(1)`
- read properties immediately (i.e `bone.matrix.elements[0]`) => no change
- next frame, read properties again => no change
- next frame, read properties again => properties changed

Here is a fiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/brunoimbrizi/ggjjk4jg/

Is there a way update the properties immediately so they can be read synchronously? I would like to be able to do the following:

```
mixer.update(1);                   // advance 1 second
myVar = bone.matrix.elements[0];   // store updated value
mixer.update(-1);                  // go back to original frame
```